# IF function not responding

Tags: javascript, if-statement, google-apps-script

I've some issues with an if statement. I'm working on a Google sheet, that may be the reason with this doesn't work. I just got into coding. The main problem is the if statement; I ask to do something if XY is bigger than 100: the problem is no matter what number it's even under or over 100 will still get through the if.

Here's my code

```js
function myfunction() {
  
  var exp = ("a38");
  var expmax = ("B38");
  var exptotal = ("e31");
  var level = ("f31");
  var bronze = ("C2");
  var fer = ("D2");
  var mitrite = ("E2");
  var adamantit = ("F2");
  var runite = ("G2");
  var dragonite = ("H2");
  var expmoin= exp -expmax

  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(bronze).setValue(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(bronze).getValue() + 1);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('a38').setValue(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('a38').getValue() + 8);

IF (exptotal >= 100) {    
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(level).setValue(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(level).getValue() + 1);     
  
  }
else {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('G31').setValue(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('G31').getValue() + 1);    
  } 
}
```

Comment: you should write `if` lowercase, not with capital letters.

Comment: also `"e31" >= 100` will always return `false`. Retrieve the cell content before comparing it to 100. Not sure what you're expecting by surrounding strings with parenthesis.

Comment: It is not necessary to put a string `"..."` in between parenthesis. That is for Vanilla Js, I'm not so sure about Google's stuff

Comment: OK, i've removed the parenthesis and i putted the IF in lowercase. For now, i'm trying to fin a way to retrieve the cell content before the comparaison.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Some introductory explanation

I recommend you to store the active sheet in a variable with [getActiveSheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getactivesheet). This method performs over [Spreadsheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet). You can get one with [getActiveSpreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getactivespreadsheet) if you are using a [Container-bound Scripts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound) or with [openById](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyidid) or [openByUrl](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyurlurl) that also work on [Standalone Scripts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/standalone)

Furthermore, I also recommend you to define all the cells that you are going to use at the beginning of your code.

Finally, to retrieve the cell content of any cell you need to use [getValue](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue). This method operates on [Ranges](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range), like [setValue](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue).

Applying all this information, the script would look like this:

### Code

```
function myfunction() {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()

  var g31cell = ("G31")
  var exp = ("a38");
  var expmax = ("B38");
  var exptotal = ("e31");
  var level = ("f31");
  var bronze = ("C2");
  var fer = ("D2");
  var mitrite = ("E2");
  var adamantit = ("F2");
  var runite = ("G2");
  var dragonite = ("H2");
  var expmoin = exp - expmax

  sheet.getRange(bronze).setValue(sheet.getRange(bronze).getValue() + 1);
  sheet.getRange(exp).setValue(sheet.getRange(exp).getValue() + 8);

  var exptotalValue = sheet.getRange(exptotal).getValue()
  if (exptotalValue >= 100) {
    sheet.getRange(level).setValue(sheet.getRange(level).getValue() + 1);

  }
  else {
    sheet.getRange(g31cell).setValue(sheet.getRange(g31cell).getValue() + 1);
  }

}
```

### Reference:

- [Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet)
- [Spreadsheet: getActiveSheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getactivesheet)
- [SpreadsheetApp: getActiveSpreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getactivespreadsheet)
- [SpreadsheetApp: openById](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyidid)
- [SpreadsheetApp: openByUrl](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyurlurl)
- [Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)
- [Range: getValue](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue)
- [Range: setValue](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue)
- [Container-bound Scripts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound)
- [Standalone Scripts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/standalone)